# Application has crashed when clicking input file from webview

Tags: android, webview

I'm making an application out of a `WebView` and what I need to do is upload an image to the `database`. I am using a `Navigation Bar Activity` and at the top of the `Navigation Bar` I have an item where it redirects me to a page where I can upload an image.

I added some back end code but whenever I try to click on it, the application crashes and says **"Application has stopped working"** and the logcat error doesn't contain anything unusual.

This is my code:

```
 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.addPost) {
            WebView web = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.layoutHome);
            web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
            webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webSettings = web.getSettings();
            webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
            webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
            webView.setWebViewClient(new Client());
            webView.setWebChromeClient(new ChromeClient());
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
                webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
            }
            else if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=11 && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {
                webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
            }
            web.loadUrl("http://192.168.0.10/BuyAndSell/Mobile/addItem.php");
        }
        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

> Edit: Logcat

```
04-05 14:46:07.320 1554-14992/? V/FA: Using measurement service
04-05 14:46:07.320 1554-14992/? V/FA: Connecting to remote service
04-05 14:46:07.330 1554-14992/? V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 34708363
04-05 14:46:07.810 1554-14992/? D/FA: Connected to remote service
04-05 14:46:07.810 1554-14992/? V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 1
```

Comment: Is it throwing null pointer exception? Seems it may be !

Comment: show your logcat

Comment: @Piyush my logcat doesn't say anything about it being an NPE

Comment: remember version 23 above require you to request permission during run time. Is there anywhere in your code require some permission which previously you require it on android manifest?   https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: I have to add a screen below in the answer (although it is not an answer, but i am not sure where i can put that). Wish you can tell us more what did you see on the logcat after your app crashes.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Since your app has crashed. there will be some information on the logcat, select 'Error' as the screenshot below, and what does logcat show you?